# Codeigniter POST Multiple Selectbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, multiple-select

I couldn't post multiple selectbox values properly. My code are below;

View

```
<form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('uye/ekle/paket_ekle'); ?>">
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="makaleler[]">
<?php foreach($makaleler as $m) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $m['id']; ?>"><?php echo $m['isim']; ?></option>
<?php } ?></select>
```

Controller

```
function paket_ekle() {

    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('fiyat', 'Fiyat', 'required|numeric');
    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE) {
        $this -> paket();


    } else {
        if ($this -> M_ekle -> paket_ekle()) {
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('ok', 'Paketiniz yönetici onayına gönderildi!');
            redirect('uye/ekle/paket');
        } else {
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('hata', 'Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.');
            redirect('uye/ekle/paket');
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
function paket_ekle()
{

    foreach($this->input->post('makaleler') as $mak){

    $data = array
                (
                'makaleler'             => $mak,
                'fiyat'                 => $this->input->post('fiyat'),
                'yazar'                 => $this->session->userdata('id'),

                );
     }
    if($this->db->insert('paketler', $data))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I found a few questions like this here but I couldn't solve it. So, I'm sorry for re-asking this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try $value['makaleler'] = $this->input->post('makaleler');print_r($value);

Comment: Can you close the </select> tag and try.

Comment: @saty With this way, it posts only first id.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS it's already closed, I just forgot to write it here.

Comment: Hope you specified form method as post rt.?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('uye/ekle/paket_ekle'); ?>">